# Will I receive rewards for all epochs when I switch my stake pool?

Tags: ada, stake-pool, staking

I am currently delegating my ADA to stake pool A. I want to switch to stake pool B. What exactly happens with my rewards when I do this?

Will there be an interruption in the reward payout or will I still get rewards for every epoch?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will continue to get rewards every epoch. Cardano works on epoch "snapshots" that occur every 5 days. It takes 3 epochs to get paid the rewards from a snapshot. This means that if you change stake pools, it will take 3 epochs (from the first snapshot that the change is effective) to receive rewards from the other pool. However, the other two epochs you will still get rewards because the snapshots with your ADA in the old pool will be paying out.

The only time you stop getting rewards is when you stop delegating your ADA and that is included in a snapshot. After the snapshot with your wallet undelegated, you will get the remaining rewards for the next two epochs and rewards will stop on the third epoch.